# Starting the Ionic dev server timed out (420000 ms) on Visual Studio Code

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a sample app created using ionic [ionic start --v2 myApp tabs]
Visual Studio Code is throwing this error and changing the timeout isn't helping:

> Starting the Ionic dev server timed out (420000 ms)

Comment: related https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/134

Comment: @Eric I have already looked at that issue. I changed the timeout as suggested. The new timeout settings get applied, but it always times out after the configured amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the timeout value from `launch.json` file as long as you're using the Cordova extension on Visual Studio Code by adjusting the `devServerTimeout` key:

```
{
            "name": "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "serve",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "devServerAddress": "localhost",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "ionicLiveReload": true,
            "devServerTimeout": 500000
},
```

if you're still facing an issue can you provide the log from the console.